# How to create an array like this in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create an array like this:

```
s1 = [[[2011-12-02, 3],[2011-12-05,3],[5,13.1],[2011-12-07,2]]];
```

How to create it using a `for` loop? I have another array that contains the values as

```
2011-12-02,3,2011-12-05,3,2011-12-07,2
```

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions:

```
var input = ['2011-12-02',3,'2011-12-05',3,'2011-12-07',2]
//or: var input = '2011-12-02,3,2011-12-05,3,2011-12-07,2'.split(",");
var output = [];
for(i = 0; i < input.length; i += 2) {
  output.push([t[i], t[i + 1]])
}
```

Comment: +1. You posted before me :) here is the working code http://jsfiddle.net/gbsandeep/3Hqpc/

Answer (score 0):

If your values always come in pairs:

```
var str = '2011-12-02,3,2011-12-05,3,2011-12-07,2',//if you start with a string then you can split it into an array by the commas
    arr = str.split(','),
    len = arr.length,
    out = [];

for (var i = 0; i < len; i+=2) {
    out.push([[arr[i]], arr[(i + 1)]]);
}
```

The `out` variable is an array in the format you requested.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hj6Eh/

Comment: '2011-12-02,3,2011-12-05,3,2011-12-07,2' is not a string it is an array . Then how to do this ? Plz help me

Comment: @user174404 `arr` is an array formatted like in your question, I just added the string bit on to show that it's easy to go from a string to an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create an array which holds a set of arrays.

```
var myArray = [];
for(var i=0; i<100;i++){
   myArray.push([2011-12-02, 3]); // The values inside push should be dynamic as per your requirement
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s1 = [];

for (x = 0, y = something.length; x < y; x++) {
    var arr = [];
    arr[0] = something[x].date;
    arr[1] = something[x].otherVal;
    s1.push(arr);
}
```

I've guessed here that the date and the other numerical value are properties of some other object, but that needn't be the case...